# How can I convert contiguous letters to number separated by dash in Java?

Tags: java

I'd like to convert alphabet letters to numbers and if the alphabet letters are contiguous, I want to make it separated by dash (-). I will leave non-alphabetic character unchanged shown below:

```
Input string: "20 pizzas an!d, 1 Apple a b c"

Output string: "20 16-9-26-26-1-19 1-14!4, 1 1-16-16-12-5 1 2 3"
```

Note: a/A =1, b/B =2, ... y/Y = 25, z/Z = 26

Comment: Not sure you are expecting someone to write a program for you ? or seeking just  program logic. In case you are asking for logic, its simple. Loop through all chars in given sentence, and keep replacing non numeric, with your numeric equivalent. Also add a dash in between, unless previous char is space.

Comment: I am new to Java so I need your help. I feel like I should use a regular expression to grab the contiguous letters and use split method to add dash in between but I am not sure if that's a right approach.

Comment: @Girish, what about "!d"? There is an exclamation point  in front of "d" here and you don't add dash

Comment: I would really appreciate if anybody could provide an algorithm

Comment: Start by trying to describe a solution **in words**. Programming is primarily about problem solving. And humans primarily solve problems using the spoken and written languages we learn from childhood. Use this tool and then when you have a good solution, translate it into a programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite simple and easy. Just go though your string and check the letters. If it found, then replace it with the number and add `-` in case of previous character is also a letter:

```
public static String convert(String str) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    boolean alphabetic = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char ch = str.charAt(i);

        if (Character.isAlphabetic(ch)) {
            if (alphabetic)
                buf.append('-');
            buf.append(Character.toLowerCase(ch) - 'a' + 1);
            alphabetic = true;
        } else {
            buf.append(ch);
            alphabetic = false;
        }
    }

    return buf.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be like this

```
 String alphabetic  = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
 char[] charArray = input.toCharArray();
 for (int i = 0, charArrayLength = charArray.length; i < charArrayLength; i++) {
        char ch = charArray[i];
        int index = alphabetic.indexOf(Character.toLowerCase(ch));
        if (alphabetic.indexOf(ch) >= 0 || index >= 0) {
            String replace = String.valueOf(index+ 1);
            if (i+1 != charArray.length && alphabetic.contains(String.valueOf(charArray[i+1])))
                replace =replace+"-";
            input = input.replace(ch + "", replace);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't check the contiguous letters. I only want to add dash between contiguous letters

Comment: see updated answer!

Answer (score 0):

Working java code with explanation in the comments:

1. Convert input string to upper case
2. Initialise hashmap of  with values
3. Iterate over the string and append char in stringbuilder and append `-` iff the character is not the last character or if the character is proceeded by a valid char(A-Z) else don't append `-`

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       //Expected output = "20 16-9-26-26-1-19 1-14!4, 1 1-16-16-12-5 1 2 3"
       String inputString = "20 pizzas an!d, 1 Apple a b c";
       Map<Character, Integer> charValueMap = new HashMap<>();
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

       //Converting all to upper-case for easy access of their value from map
       inputString = inputString.toUpperCase();

       //initialising map with values
       int value = 1;
       for (char ch = 'A'; ch <= 'Z'; ++ch) {
           charValueMap.put(ch, value++);
       }

       for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++) {
           char ch = inputString.charAt(i);
           if (charValueMap.containsKey(ch)) {
               sb.append(charValueMap.get(ch));

               /* condition checks to only append '-' if it is not the last character or
             there is some valid char[A-Z] after current char */
               if (!(i+1 == inputString.length() || !charValueMap.containsKey(inputString.charAt(i+1)))) {
                   sb.append("-");
               }
           } else {
               sb.append(ch);
           }
       }

       System.out.println(sb.toString());
   }
   ```

Comment: @user7755336 I think using `Map` is overhead for this simple task